# Desktop Notification working only Chrome Browser?

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications

i'm new to javascript i'm create desktop notification using JAVASCRIPT,but that is working only chrome browser Why Not all Browser ?
i'm try :-

```
const notification = new Notification("new msg!", {
                body: "hey Man",
            });
```

Thank You

Comment: https://caniuse.com/notifications

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#browser_compatibility

Comment: It would be strange if this is the case because Edge and Chrome have the same JS runtime and many other features so if something works on one it should work on the other. Maybe it's a permission  issue in that you are only allowing Chrome to to show desktop notifications